# URL Rewrite rule for IIS to replace folder path in everypage

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

We are having more than 300 pages in my website project. Over the time we have created a new server which is secure. This server is specially used for all the images in website.

So here is the scenario:

- current implementation for images ( in aspx, in css )

  ```
  http://www.mysite.com/assets/common/image1.jpg
  ```
- sometimes in webpage and css it is specified like this

  ```
  ~/assets/common/image1.jpg
  ```
- would like to use somethig like this.

  ```
  http://www.static.mysite.com/common/image1.jpg
  ```
- and for secure pages

  ```
  https://www.static.mysite.com/common/image1.jpg
  ```

So as you can see all the images are coming from `~/assets` folder BUT now I want to create a rule replacing `~/assets` with `http://static.mysite.com`

How can I achieve this in IIS using rewrite rule.

## EXAMPLE:

## ASPX

```
 <img src="/assets/common/image1.jpg" id="ImageId1" alt="Image" width="100" height="100" />

<img src="http://mysite.com/assets/common/image2.jpg" id="ImageId2" alt="Image" width="100" height="100" />
```

Would like to have IIS rule, when finds above code, replace it with http://static.mysite.com/common/image1.jpg

```
 <img src="http://static.mysite.com/common/image1.jpg" id="ImageId1" alt="Image" width="100" height="100" />


<img src="http://static.mysite.com/common/image2.jpg" id="ImageId2" alt="Image" width="100" height="100" />
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to create Outbound Rule in IIS. Rule will need following:

1. Precondition should only check html files (I used default IsHTML)
2. In "Matching the content with" choose elements in which you would like to check links
3. Pattern is `^(.*)/assets/(.*)`
4. Action properties is http://static.mysite.com/{R:2}. R:2 reffers to second () in above regular expression. You could check what you need after click of "Test pattern" button.

Bellow simple rule which meets above:

[image]

Comment: How to configure this using `web.Config`, I want all the `Images` folder , `css` and `js`  inside Content folder to point to  azure cdn  ?

Comment: @stom all above changes are visible in web.config so you can copy-paste them

Answer (score 6):

You can try this

```
<rule name="assets redirection" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="^(.*)/(assets)/(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/{R:3}" />
</rule>
```

It will redirect `whatever/assets/common/image1.jpg` to `whatever/common/image1.jpg`

Update:

```
<rule name="assets redirection" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="^(.*)/(assets)/(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="static.mysite.com/{R:3}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: i would like it to redirect to http://static.mysite.com/common/image1.jpg by replacing http://mysite.com/assets/

Comment: I am using godaddy for hosting. So should I drop the above rewrite in the individual website virtual directory/folder or at the root?

Comment: @SnehaJavalkar, Depends on which level you want to apply the rule. you can define it at root level also

Answer (score 2):

umm some how you can do like this

```
string imageUrl= Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/Image/logo/Logo.png";
```

Scheme is your web Schemes http or https etc.
Authority is your web domain name with port if any.
 Then here it goes your image url completely.

I have used this logo url for the ssrs report service and got fine.Hope it ll work for you.

Comments and queries are welcome .
Thank you.